# combineLatest throws TS2349 with 6 or more streams

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

This is my first foray into RxJS, so if there is a better solution I am all for it. My goal is to collect related objects and join them (essentially a sql left join) in code. This stems from me using an Angular In Memory API object to serve as the DB until such time it is established.

When I combine Plans, Specieses, Codebooks, UpstreamModalities, and TissueProcessions this code works as expected. When I include the Probes, Imaging, and Analysises streams I get a headache of a error blob to read. Essentially every line in the array.map function throws the TS2349 error, even the ones that worked before adding the remaining three sources.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Plan } from '../plan';
import { PlanService } from '../plan.service';
import { DatabaseService } from 'src/app/serivces/database.service';
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs';
import { map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-plans-list',
  templateUrl: './plans-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./plans-list.component.scss']
})
export class PlansListComponent implements OnInit {
  plans$ = combineLatest([
    this.planService.getPlans(),
    this.databaseService.getSpecieses(),
    this.databaseService.getCodebooks(),
    this.databaseService.getUpstreamModalities(),
    this.databaseService.getTissueProcessions(),
    this.databaseService.getProbes(),
    this.databaseService.getImagings(),
    this.databaseService.getAnalysises(),
  ])
    .pipe(
      tap(x => console.log(`Plans.join lookup tables: `, x)),
      map(
        // destructuring
        ([plans, 
          specieses, 
          codebooks, 
          modalities, 
          tissues,
          probes,
          imagings, 
          analysises
        ]) =>
          plans.map(plan =>
            ({
              ...plan,
              species: specieses.find(x => x.id === plan.speciesId).shortName,
              codebook: codebooks.find(x => x.id === plan.codebookId).codebookName,
              upstreamModality: modalities.find(x => x.id === plan.upstreamModalityId).SOPName,
              tissueProcession: tissues.find(x => x.id === plan.tissueProcessionId).SOPName,
              probe: probes.find(x => x.id === plan.probeId).SOPName,
              imaging: imagings.find(x => x.id === plan.imagingId).SOPName,
              analysis: analysises.find(x => x.id === plan.analysisId).SOPName,
            }) as Plan
          )
      )
    )


  constructor(
    private planService: PlanService,
    private databaseService: DatabaseService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {  }
}
```

Is this TS validation just choking up on the volume of streams? Since the code still compiles and executes as expected.

```
ERROR in src/app/plans/plans-list/plans-list.component.ts(40,11): error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '(<U>(callbackfn: (value: Plan, index: number, array: Plan[]) => U, thisArg?: any) => U[]) | (<U>(callbackfn: (value: StandardOperatingProcess, index: number, array: StandardOperatingProcess[]) => U, thisArg?: any) => U[]) | (<U>(callbackfn: (value: Species, index: number, array: Species[]) => U, thisArg?: any) => U[...' has no compatible call signatures.
    src/app/plans/plans-list/plans-list.component.ts(43,24): error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '{ <S extends Plan>(predicate: (this: void, value: Plan, index: number, obj: Plan[]) => value is S, thisArg?: any): S; (predicate: (value: Plan, index: number, obj: Plan[]) => boolean, thisArg?: any): Plan; } | { ...; } | { ...; } | { ...; }' has no compatible call signatures.
    src/app/plans/plans-list/plans-list.component.ts(44,25): error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '{ <S extends Plan>(predicate: (this: void, value: Plan, index: number, obj: Plan[]) => value is S, thisArg?: any): S; (predicate: (value: Plan, index: number, obj: Plan[]) => boolean, thisArg?: any): Plan; } | { ...; } | { ...; } | { ...; }' has no compatible call signatures.
    src/app/plans/plans-list/plans-list.component.ts(45,33): error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '{ <S extends Plan>(predicate: (this: void, value: Plan, index: number, obj: Plan[]) => value is S, thisArg?: any): S; (predicate: (value: Plan, index: number, obj: Plan[]) => boolean, thisArg?: any): Plan; } | { ...; } | { ...; } | { ...; }' has no compatible call signatures.
    src/app/plans/plans-list/plans-list.component.ts(46,33): error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '{ <S extends Plan>(predicate: (this: void, value: Plan, index: number, obj: Plan[]) => value is S, thisArg?: any): S; (predicate: (value: Plan, index: number, obj: Plan[]) => boolean, thisArg?: any): Plan; } | { ...; } | { ...; } | { ...; }' has no compatible call signatures.
    src/app/plans/plans-list/plans-list.component.ts(47,22): error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '{ <S extends Plan>(predicate: (this: void, value: Plan, index: number, obj: Plan[]) => value is S, thisArg?: any): S; (predicate: (value: Plan, index: number, obj: Plan[]) => boolean, thisArg?: any): Plan; } | { ...; } | { ...; } | { ...; }' has no compatible call signatures.
    src/app/plans/plans-list/plans-list.component.ts(48,24): error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '{ <S extends Plan>(predicate: (this: void, value: Plan, index: number, obj: Plan[]) => value is S, thisArg?: any): S; (predicate: (value: Plan, index: number, obj: Plan[]) => boolean, thisArg?: any): Plan; } | { ...; } | { ...; } | { ...; }' has no compatible call signatures.
    src/app/plans/plans-list/plans-list.component.ts(49,25): error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '{ <S extends Plan>(predicate: (this: void, value: Plan, index: number, obj: Plan[]) => value is S, thisArg?: any): S; (predicate: (value: Plan, index: number, obj: Plan[]) => boolean, thisArg?: any): Plan; } | { ...; } | { ...; } | { ...; }' has no compatible call signatures.
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is true, maximum number of source Observables is 6, see https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/observable/combineLatest.ts#L68.

However, The only reason is that it's unlikely to have so many inputs so there are no function overloads defined for that. This still doesn't restrict you from combining multiple `combineLatest`s:

```
combineLatest([
  combineLatest([s1, s2, ...]),
  combineLatest([s7, s8, ...]),
]).pipe(
  map(([results1, results2]) => [...results1, ...results2]),
);
```

Btw, this is a TypeScript error that you should be able to suppress with `@ts-ignore` (even though you might miss other TypeScript errors later):

```
// @ts-ignore
plans$ = combineLatest([
  this.planService.getPlans(),
  this.databaseService.getSpecieses(),
  ...
  this.databaseService.getAnalysises(),
])
```

Comment: Thanks martin, I just found that page and was about to create my own answer when I saw yours come in. Thanks! This was a doozy. Also, I prefer not to squelch any kind of code linting/syntax issues and instead address the issue. Unless there is no other solution. :)

Answer (score 3):

Just for the sake of completeness (and having all the answer available on stackoverflow, and not in some link), the solution from the issue Balu [linked](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/3601#issuecomment-384711601) is simply declaring the types each observable will emit:

```
combineLatest<any>(a$, b$, c$, d$, e$, f$).pipe(
  // Manually typed arguments below :(
  map(([a, b, c, d, e, f]: [string, number, string, Foo, Bar, Baz]) => doStuff(a, b, c, d, e, f))
)
```

This can be greatly simplified by defining a new Type with the expected param types.

```
export type CombinedSources = [string, number, string, Foo, Bar, Baz];

combineLatest<any>(a$, b$, c$, d$, e$, f$).pipe(
  map(([a, b, c, d, e, f]: CombinedSources) => doStuff(a, b, c, d, e, f))
)
```

Answer (score 2):

This way losing types:

```
combineLatest([
  combineLatest([s1, s2, ...]),
  combineLatest([s7, s8, ...]),
]).pipe(
  map(([results1, results2]) => [...results1, ...results2]),
);
```

I didnt found the way to save it except this:

```
combineLatest([
  combineLatest([A, B, C]),
  combineLatest([D, E, F]),
  combineLatest([G]),
]).pipe(
  map(([r1, r2, r3]) => {
    return [...r1, ...r2, ...r3] as [
      typeof r1[0],
      typeof r1[1],
      typeof r1[2],
      typeof r2[0],
      typeof r2[1],
      typeof r2[2],
      typeof r3[0],
    ];
  }))
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this. It has slightly different semantics - it does not emit a new combination when `r` slice emits:

```
combineLatest([s1, s2, ...])
      .pipe(
        withLatestFrom(r1),
        map(([[s1, s2, ...], r1]) => {
           ...
        })
      )
```